# How to pass dialog property value to AJAX request in sightly JAVA Script USE API.?

Tags: javascript, ajax, aem, sightly, htl

Am using server-side JavaScript USE API to read the dialog properties like below

```
use(function () {
var myproperty = properties.get("renderpagetype");
return { callajaxvariable: myproperty,
};
});
```

How to pass/get this dialog property value and call an AJAX request in sightly.?
(i.e. i need the dialog value which has been retrieved by JS USE API into a page level Java script usage).

Comment: Please be more specific, what exactly is authored for the property "renderpagetype" and where are you sending an ajax request?

Comment: Its a string value and i need the string value from the dialog property to pass in a AJAX URI as a parameter for the REST call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of what you are trying to achieve based on your question:

**simple.js**

```
use(function () {
  var myproperty = properties.get("renderpagetype");
  return {callajaxvariable: myproperty};
});
```

**simple.html**

```
// simple.html
<script data-sly-use.simple="simple.js">

  /* assuming you use jquery */
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/path/to/backend/servlet",
    someParam: "${simple.callajaxvariable @ context='scriptString'}"
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Awsome Ahmed this sovled my problem `<script data-sly-use.simple="simple.js">`